# How to create object widget in other widgets in QT

Tags: c++, qt

In my application im having three widgets named as "Widget" , "one" and "two" . i tried to create the objects of the widget in main function as pass it as an argument to another widgets . it compiles successfully but application crashed before running , refer my code below and guide me,

```
//main.cpp
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "widget.h"
#include "one.h"
#include "two.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Widget *w;
  One *one;
  Two *two;

   w->GetObject(one,two);
   one->GetObject(w,two);
   two->GetObject(one,w);
   w->show();
   return a.exec();
}

//widget.cpp
#include "widget.h"
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
}

void Widget::GetObject(One *onee, Two *twoo)
{
   one=onee;
   two=twoo;
}

//widget.h
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include "ui_widget.h"
class One;
class Two;
class Widget : public QWidget, private Ui::Widget
{
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
        explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
        One *one;
        Two *two; 
        void GetObject(One *onee, Two *twoo);
};
#endif // WIDGET_H

//one.cpp
#include "one.h"
One::One(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}

void One::GetObject(Widget *widgett, Two *twoo)
{
  widget = widgett;
  two = twoo;
}

void One::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   widget->show();
}

//one.h
#ifndef ONE_H
#define ONE_H

#include "ui_one.h"
class Widget;
class Two;
class One : public QWidget, private Ui::One
{
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
       explicit One(QWidget *parent = 0);
        Widget *widget;
        Two *two;
        void GetObject(Widget *widgett, Two *twoo);
   private slots:
         void on_pushButton_clicked();
 };
 #endif // ONE_H
```

Comment: An **error**. We need an error to help you :)

Comment: @Thomas : The error is "The program has unexpectedly finished." while running

Comment: `Widget *w; w->GetObject(one,two);` All three of `w`, `one` and `two` are uninitialized variables containing random garbage. Your program has not actually created any objects of type `Widget`, `One` or `Two`, so of course it can't call methods on objects that don't exist.

Comment: @igor: you are right , i changed like Widget *w = new Widget; and now its working fine.

Comment: If you found the solution, please write an answer and mark this answer als solving.